# How can I see analytics from specific ad network on Firebase?

Tags: firebase, tracking

For example, if I am running Facebook ads, can I see the analytics (installs, uninstalls, revenue, ...) from those ads?

Answer (score 1):

You can see analytics from specific ad networks by marking these events that you care about (like `first_open` or `in_app_purchase`) as Conversion Events in Firebase.

From the Firebase console, select **Analytics** -> **Attribution**, then turn on the events you want to track.

After you do that, go into the **Network Settings** part of the page and add whatever ad networks you want to start tracking. Right now, Firebase has support for several dozen networks, but I'm afraid Facebook is not currently among them, so you won't be able to get Facebook attribution analytics within Firebase.

You can find out more information about all of this from the [help center documentation](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317518?hl=en). Good luck!